# Why do the spoilers on the 737 only deploy to the flight detent after a flaps up landing?

Tags: landing, flight-controls, airline-operations, boeing-737

Following an all flaps up (no flap) landing, the SPEED BRAKE
lever will not move beyond the FLIGHT DETENT and the spoilers
will not fully deploy (for reference this is stated in the Fcom 9.20.14 rev 2013).

What is the reason for this? With flap up the speed will be high and if we could use the full deflection, we can reduce the landing distance, so why restrict it?